# Retrieve data from MySQL database using innerJoin method Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I'm trying to retrieve data from DBA using Yii2 methods. My problem is when I'm building the query using yii2 query builder like innerJoin, only the column related to the model that I'm starting from are returned.

```
$Categories =  CategoryOfItemsTrans::find()
        ->innerJoin('category_of_items','category_of_items_trans.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID = category_of_items.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID')
        ->where('category_of_items.CATEGORY_FLAG = \''.$CategoryFlag.'\' AND category_of_items_trans.LANGUAGE_ID ='.$LanguageID)
        ->all();
```

Here an example, I just receive columns related to 'CategoryOfItemsTrans' Model. What I need to retrieve all columns of both tables.

Comment: You can use `select([ ])` and give the column names that you want inside it.

Comment: i have use it , and i have added the columns name in the first model and  configured them as safe and still don't returned in the response.

Comment: Thank you i have found the solution...i have returned the response asArray. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use asArray() and you will get result in array. Try This

```
$Categories =  CategoryOfItemsTrans::find()
        ->innerJoin('category_of_items','category_of_items_trans.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID = category_of_items.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID')
        ->where('category_of_items.CATEGORY_FLAG = \''.$CategoryFlag.'\' AND category_of_items_trans.LANGUAGE_ID ='.$LanguageID)
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is making a query that will give you an array of objects of type "CategoryOfItemsTrans" and what you need is not that.
That is to say, you are using the "find" method of the model, so it will never give you back what you expect.

If you expect to receive some columns, you will have to make a simple query so that   .
Try like that

```
 $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['ci.*', 'cit.*email'])
            ->from('category_of_items_trans as cit')
            ->innerJoin('category_of_items as 
                ci','category_of_items_trans.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID = 
              category_of_items.CATEGORY_OF_ITEM_ID')
            ->where('category_of_items.CATEGORY_FLAG = \''.$CategoryFlag.'\' AND 
             category_of_items_trans.LANGUAGE_ID ='.$LanguageID)
            ->all();
```